# Where is the "Add vector layer"-button in GRASS 6.4.4. plug-in QGIS 2.10.1?

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-plugins, layers

I've just downloaded and installed the new version of QGIS 2.10.1 with GRASS 6.4.4. 
When opening a new GRASS mapset and importing layers, I missed the button "Add a new vector layer". I've updated the GRASS plugin, but again the button wasn't there (all other GRASS symbols except "add raster layer" were visuable).

It's maybe a stupid question of a GIS beginner, but what can I Do? Is there an option to add (not import) a vector layer via the GRASS toolbox?

Comment: I think I read that some functionalities were moved/are going to be moved to the browser within QGIS. Haven't tried myself yet.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open "QGIS Browser 2.10.1 with GRASS 6.4.4".
2. Find the vector or raster layer in the "header window".
3. Click on the layer and drag it over to your QGIS "Layers Box".

Answer (score 2):

*Add vector layer* or *Add raster layer* icons are not available any more as of the `Grass` toolbar.

On new Qgis versions (I am running Qgis 2.18) you need to look for the layers in the `browser panel`. If it is not open as in my case because I never used before, you can activate it by going to the menu `View` then `Panels` and click on `Browser Panel`.

Go to the folder of your gis data (or the `grassdata` folder) and expand the *location* and *mapset* as folders. To add the items under this folder into your Qgis project you can either:

1. right click them and chose `Add Layer` or
2. drag and drop them to the `Layers Panel` or the canvas

If the Grass 7 vector provider and the Grass 7 raster provider are loaded in QGIS, the location items will display a Grass icon.

Source: http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html#id3