# 'Add GRASS vector layer' button in QGIS 2.16.2 with GRASS 7.0.4?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, grass-7.0, qgis-grass-plugin

I could not find 'Add GRASS vector layer' button in QGis 2.16.2 with GRASS 7.0.4?
Can someone help?

Comment: Just noticed that this post is also related: [Where is the “Add vector layer”-button in GRASS 6.4.4. plug-in QGIS 2.10.1?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155794/where-is-the-add-vector-layer-button-in-grass-6-4-4-plug-in-qgis-2-10-1)

Answer (score 2):

I think that button has been depreciated for some time. You can follow the instructions described in:

- [Loading GRASS raster and vector layers](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html#loading-grass-raster-and-vector-layers)
- [Importing data into a GRASS LOCATION via drag and drop](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html#importing-data-into-a-grass-location-via-drag-and-drop)